# Send data to controller while calling nyro modal manually

Tags: razor, nyromodal

Working with ASP.NET MVC3 Razor view.
I need to open a nyro modal manually. So, I am doing this. And it works fine.

```
            $.nmManual("/Reports/Reports/AddNewTask", {
            sizes: {
                initW: 2,
                initH: 2
            },
            resizable: true,
            closeOnEscape: true
        });
```

But, I can not figure out how can I send a string to the controller action "AddNewTask" while opening the modal window.

Comment: Can you get the string when you click the link handled by nyroModal?